# .NET 2.0 - TimeZone Conversion

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, timezone

I need help in writing a function which should take a datetime object and target timezone and it should return a datetime object after converting it to the target timezone - WHILE considering Day Light Saving of either target or current timezone.

Also, need a method to enumerate all available timezones.

I have been able to achieve this all in .NET 3.5, but my client's server is running .NET 2.0 and upgrading it is not possible.

Anyone who can help?

Good Day;

Comment: post what you have. Did you use a .NET 3.5 only feature ?

Comment: Are you sure you can't deal with it by just converting to/from UTC on the client and server side? If you send an UTC time from the client the server can then convert it to its local time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need something like the Olson database to obtain such info, as .NET 2.0 knows only about the current time zone.

Look here:
http://zoneinfo.codeplex.com/

Edit: Here's how to use it:
[CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/locale/zoneinfo_dotnet_api.aspx)

Comment: Thanks... lemme check. I have found another article on CP, http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/timezoneconversions.aspx, but this one does not work on Vista and Win2K8 I guess....

Comment: Well, that's a lot of P/Invoke going on here :) Imagine if you have to port this to Silverlight or Mono. Interesting approach nonetheless - might work on Vista too, but you have to test it.

Comment: No, it is not working on VISTA, about the CodePlex library your specified, I can't seem to find the download link :| ... is it discarded?

Comment: No, but it's only available as source code. Shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: As an update to this, the ZoneInfo project above has had an updated which patched in a number of bug fixes.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's always `System.TimeZone`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.aspx

Comment: System.timezoneinfo is introduced in .NET 3.5.